# How do I change virtualmin default URL on Amazon AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, webserver, ip-address, virtualmin

I just installed `virtualmin` on an Amazon EC2 instance and at the end of the installation it gave me a link to access virtualmin as `https://ip_address:10000`

However the instance’s IP address that is accessible from the internet seems to be entirely different, let’s call it `true_ip_address`.

I am unable to access virtualmin from `https://ip_address:10000` and hoping to change the auto configured ip address to the `https://true_ip_address:10000`. Can I do this from the server command prompt? Please advice. Thanks!

I tried using virtualmin modify domain but I think I’m not using the right syntax. Documentation doesn’t seem to have the usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualmin doesn't detect your public IP address during the installation. So it'll print the internal IP address which you can't use to access the server. Just swap the internal IP address with your external IP address and you should be able to see the login screen.

But things don't stop here. You need to setup a password for your root account before login in. The UNIX root account I mean. Following commands should do it.

Change to root account,

```
sudo -i
```

Set the password,

```
passwd
```

You should be able to login after this. But to make Virtualmin fully compatible your AWS server, you need to set your external IP address as **Default IP address for DNS records** in Virtualmin networking settings.

Source: [Configure Virtualmin Networking settings for AWS EC2 and LightSail](https://vpsfix.com/community/announcements/configure-virtualmin-networking-settings-for-aws-ec2-and-lightsail/)